# How can I auto-populate in set fields with the word typed in a specific place in Overleaf/LaTex?

Tags: overleaf, auto-completion, forms

I´m applying for different jobs, more or less in the same areas but the names might differ (Analyst, Business Analyst, etc.). Hence, in order not to have to review the text every time, it´d be pretty convenient if I could just type the name once in the first paragraph, and have that word copied through the text.

Comment: Just define a macro `\jobname`in your preamble, that you can change from the preamble at will.

Comment: @Bernard Are you sure that you should call a user macro jobname? ;)

Comment: @TeXnician: You're right, it's a very bad idea – let's say `\jobtitle`.